# Cannot create a private key with seahorse

Tags: seahorse

I'm trying to create a new private key (I suppose it will be an RSA key) using seahorse, but once I insert label and strength (the other fields are disabled) the create button is still disabled.

[seahorse-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3OzU.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may be a bug in Seahorse, as I just tried to generate an RSA private key on Xubuntu 18.04, and encountered the same issue.

You can instead generate the RSA private key using the command-line:

```
openssl genrsa 4096
```

You should then be able to import this into Seahorse if you need to.